# Check if application resumed from memory

Tags: android, startup, onresume

I'm wondering if there is a way to see if the application is resumed from memory.

I need to do download a file upon startup, but I don't want to use the `onResume()` because then it will be triggered when going back in stack as well.

Only when the app is resumed from e.g. the home screen.

Has anybody done anything similar?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better practice to check the file already exists locally? Maybe see if the timestamp of the file is too old and than just re-download it?

Comment: The tricky thing is that I don't know if the file is to old or not, only that I need to download it on startup. :-/

Comment: If you are downloading it from a server you have the last-modified header don't you?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to download the file in onResume(). When going back in stack, it will be triggered a download each time. Only on startup. I don't want the user to download data when it's not necessary. And I won't know if the file is out of date until it's downloaded (which is specified in the file).

Comment: Again, why won't `onCreate` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static field (e.g. a reference to the file contents, or a boolean indicating that it was recently downloaded).  If the app is killed and restarted, the static field will be null.  If it's just progressing through the app lifecycle without dying, the field won't be reset.

This may or may not be quite what you need -- there's no guarantee that an Android app won't run for days, or that it won't be completely killed and restarted frequently.  What you might actually want to do is store a timestamp alongside the file, and re-download the file if the timestamp is older than a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I now store a timestamp and the file is now checks if it needs to be downloaded each 12 hours instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onCreate`. This only gets called when the apk is started (not necessarily from the launcher) because it was destroyed and needs to be recreated.

However this means if the user starts the app from the launcher but is was already stopped it will not download the file.

read the [Life Cycle Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) for more information.

Comment: In that case the file will be downloaded on each Activity, which will result in massive unnecessary downloads. Only during startup is wanted.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself. Your question is to find if the app is resumed, where you said you wanted it to download when resuming from the home screen.
What do you mean by 'each activity' too? This is what you want according to the question, to download a file at startup

Comment: Perhaps the question needs clarification, as @Guykun points out I'm unsure if you only want the file to download once per creation of the app (`onCreate`), or something else. If you wanted it to only download the file once then this will work provided the app is not destroyed. which is normally the case.